# Archives suitable for backups

Tags: backup, encryption

For a while now I've been using SquashFS for my monthly backups (usually onto optical media with dvdisaster recovery information).  The format is reasonably convenient: good compression, can be mounted directly on Linux, command line support everywhere else.

However, it unfortunately does not support any form of transparent encryption.  Hence, I have been forced to manually GPG the files before burning them.  This also makes extraction difficult: I need to decrypt a multi-gigabyte file before I can mount it.

I am therefore looking for suggestions for archive formats that:

- Can be mounted, either natively of through FUSE or provide some means of transparent access.
- Support transparent encryption and decryption (so no need to copy and decrypt the entire archive to pull out one file).
- Support extended attributes and UNIX file permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) should be your friend with the help of [EncFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EncFS) (only encryption) or [lessfs](http://www.lessfs.com/wordpress/) (encryption and compression)

Comment: Do you happen to have any references on how lessfs can be used for backups in a portable way.  Everything on the net appears to be related to large RAID arrays.

Comment: What do you mean with "in a portable way"? Do you need to mount the images on Windows or something?